# How to define an empty 2 dimensional list instead of data = [["",""],["",""],["",""],["",""]]

Tags: python, dataframe, empty-list

How to define an empty 2 dimensional list instead of data = [["",""],["",""],["",""],["",""]]
For larger number of elements

Comment: What's the desired list dimension?

Answer (score 3):

This is a possible solution:

```
data = [['' for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
```

`m` and `n` are the desired dimensions of your list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

lis = [[] for _ in range(3)]
try it

Answer (score 0):

A simple list comprehension will do:

```
data = [["", ""] for i in range(4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   #initialize an empty 2d list
data = [[]]

#append to first list
data[0].append("a")
data[0].append("b")
data[0].append("c")

#append another list to the 2D list
data.append(['d','e','f'])

print(data)
```

this way you can make your rows or columns of any length

Comment: This doesn't answer the asker's question. They'd like to initialize a two-dimensional array with no values, not letters.

Comment: but i started with initializing an empty one , the letters are just example of data that can be appended later

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this problem would use NumPy, a math and data manipulation library for python. In that library, there's a very simple way of accomplishing this. If I want to generate an empty matrix built to hold `m` rows of `n` strings, I'd do it like this:

```py
import numpy as np    # import the library

m = 32
n = 16    # choose your array dimensions

data = np.empty((m, n), dtype=str)    # create the empty data array
```

In order to use NumPy, you'll need to install it with the terminal command, `pip install numpy`.